# How to find difference between two dates using two different DateTimePicker in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, datetimepicker

I am using two different DateTimePicker in react-native app. Below is the code for that:

Date Component:

```
function useInput() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const [date1, setDate1] = useState(new Date());
  const [date2, setDate2] = useState(new Date());

  const showMode = (currentMode) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };
  const showDatepicker = () => {
    showMode('date');
  };

  const onChange1 = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate1 = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    setDate(currentDate1);
    setDate1(currentDate1);
    console.log("date1: ", date);
  };
  const onChange2 = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate2 = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    setDate(currentDate2);
    setDate2(currentDate2);
    console.log("date1: ", date);
    console.log("date2: ", date2);
    const startDate = moment(date1);
    const timeEnd = moment(date2);
    const diff = timeEnd.diff(startDate);
    const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);
    console.log("Days:", diffDuration.days());
  };
  return {
    date,
    showDatepicker,
    show,
    mode,
    onChange1,
    onChange2,
  };
}
```

Main Component:

```
const CreatePost = () => {
const input = useInput(new Date());
const input2 = useInput(new Date());

return (
<View style={styles.dateContainer}>
    <View style={styles.startDateContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.titleInputText}>Starts On</Text>
        <View style={styles.datePickerContainer}>
            <Text>{input.date.toLocaleDateString()}</Text>
            <View style={{ marginRight: SizeConfig.blockWidth * 2 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={input.showDatepicker}>
                    <Icon
                        name="calendar-o"
                        type="font-awesome"
                        color={COLORS.blackExtraLight}
                        size={SizeConfig.blockHeight * 3.2}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {input.show && (
                    <DateTimePicker
                        testID="dateTimePicker1"
                        value={input.date}
                        mode={input.mode}
                        is24Hour={true}
                        display="default"
                        onChange={input.onChange1}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.endDateContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.titleInputText}>Ends On</Text>
        <View style={styles.datePickerContainer}>
            <Text>{input2.date.toLocaleDateString()}</Text>
            <View style={{ marginRight: SizeConfig.blockWidth * 2 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={input2.showDatepicker}>
                    <Icon
                        name="calendar-o"
                        type="font-awesome"
                        color={COLORS.blackExtraLight}
                        size={SizeConfig.blockHeight * 3.2}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {input2.show && (
                    <DateTimePicker
                        testID="dateTimePicker2"
                        value={input2.date}
                        mode={input2.mode}
                        is24Hour={true}
                        display="default"
                        onChange={input2.onChange2}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
)
}
```

My setDate1(currentDate1) and setDate2(currentDate2) state updates on second click. For Example:

selected 31st march on start date. Output on first click:

`date1:  Tue Mar 30 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

selected 31st march on start date. Output on Second click:

`date1:  Wed Mar 31 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

selected 10th April on end date. Output on first click:

`date1:  Tue Mar 30 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

`date2:  Tue Mar 30 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

`Days: 0`

selected 10th April on end date. Output on second click:

`date1:  Sat Apr 10 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

`date2:  Sat Apr 10 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

`Days: 11`

At this point, it gives the correct difference, but value of date1 also changes as same as date2.

selected 30th April on end date. Output on first click:

`date1:  Sat Apr 10 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

`date2:  Sat Apr 10 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

`Days: 11`

selected 30th April on end date. Output on second click:

`date1:  Fri Apr 30 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

`date2:  Fri Apr 30 2021 11:37:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

`Days: 0`

I think there is some problem with the way states are getting updated. But am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help me, I am stuck on this problem since 2 days.

Comment: Please provide more information about the output (if any) you are getting and what exactly is expected/incorrect.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I have updated the question, please have a look at it

Comment: First you console your variable i see that you console data not date1 change it to this  console.log("date1: ", date1);
    console.log("date2: ", date2);

Comment: @AnkitPatel The issue is still the same with the changes which you have mentioned